# How to move Horizontal Scroll View to a particular position?

Tags: android, scroll, horizontalscrollview

I am using scrollView without any listView or gridview .I have just added same views to it but know I want to programmatically scroll to a particular position. Is this possible ?

Please help I am using Horizontal Scroll?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just post your code here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use this method

```
horizontalScrollView.scrollBy(160, 0);
```

**or**

```
horizontalScrollView.scrollTo(160, 0);
```

Comment: These are x,y values in pixels to scroll to a position.